# When should I use parfum as opposed to saveur and why?

Tags: terminologie

Ice cream has parfum vanille, my yoghurt has saveur. Is this just how it is or is there a reason behind the difference like the subtle "chocolate ice cream" versus "chocolate flavour ice cream"?

Comment: La principale différence entre la saveur et le parfum est que la saveur est ressentie avec la langue tandis que le parfum est ressenti avec le nez. https://fr.sawakinome.com/articles/language/difference-between-flavour-and-fragrance.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theoretically *parfum* is "fragance" (you smell it) and *saveur* is "flavour". But *parfum* is sometimes used instead of *saveur* when talking about something sweet. Here's a definition of *parfum* found in the [TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/parfum).

> C.− Substance aromatique agréable au goût que l'on incorpore aux boissons, aux mets, aux desserts; p.méton. le goût lui-même. *Glace parfum pistache.*

When talking about ice-cream *parfum* is probably more usual then *saveur*. For yogurts I use *parfum*, but *goût* is also quite common, I know *saveur* is used too, but I think not as much as the two others.

Answer (score -1):

There is no subtle difference in meaning like the one you refer to with the chocolate ice cream example, just more or less common collocations as [None's answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/50585/1109) shows.

A manufacturer is free to use any of *parfum*, *saveur*, *goût*, or *arôme* followed by a flavor name to describe their products.

Any of them can be used regardless of whether the product contain the "real thing" or something else that mimics the flavor. If the product label doesn't state the *arôme* is *naturel* (from natural products), the *arôme* is built from a chemical process.

Alternatively, the product can be named *à la X* or *au X*. In such case, it must contain the product, *vanille* being an exception as there is no need for real *vanille* (*pods*) to be present, but only natural extract of it.